# GoogleDrive上の共有ファイルをhttp通信（非SSL）でダウンロードする方法

Tags: vb.net, google-api, google-drive-sdk

いつもお世話になっております。

現在、Windowsフォームアプリ（VB.Net）から、
GoogleDrive上の共有ファイルをダウンロードする仕組みを作成中です。

前提としてアプリを使用するユーザはGoogleアカウントを持たないので、
GoogleDriveの持ち主がアクセストークンを発行し、
それをアプリに埋め込んでダウンロードさせる予定です。

また、リクエスト時の条件として下記を指定する必要があったので、
ひとまずは"HttpWebRequest"を用いてコーディングいたしました。

【リクエスト条件】
・プロキシ指定、キャッシュポリシー指定、http通信（非SSL通信）など

---

【作成コード】

```
Dim reauest As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create("http://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/ファイルIDを設定?alt=media"), HttpWebRequest)
reauest.Method = "GET"
request.CachePolicy = "Cacheの設定"
request.Proxy = "Proxyの設定"
reauest.Headers("Authorization") = "Bearer アクセストークンを指定"
Dim response As WebResponse = req.GetResponse()
```

【下記リファレンスを参考】
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/query-parameters

---

前提条件の一つとして、非SSLのhttp通信があります。
上記コードを実際に実行すると、下記のエラーが発生します。

```
SSL is required to perform this operation.
```

勿論、URL部分を"https"に変更すればダウンロードは可能ですが
なんとかこの"http"通信を含めた今回のリクエスト条件を満たした上で、
ダウンロード出来る方法はないものでしょうか。

もし何かいい方法があれば、ご教示いただければ幸いです。
何卒、よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: 敢えて`http`でなければいけない要件(開発環境の制限)などを具体的に書いておくと、アドバイスが付きやすいと思います。 / 短い答えとしては「Google側がhttpでの通信を待ち受けてない限り不可なので、別のサイトにファイルを置いてください」などになってしまうので。

Comment: 早速のアドバイス、ありがとうございます。とにかくssl通信をしないという前提（詳細不明）でしたので、まずはGoogleDriveAPIがSSL通信を回避してダウンロード出来る手段があればと思い、今回質問させていただきました。別サイトの使用なども考慮に入れて調査してみたいと思います。